# Make data grid cells show less decimals when not focused

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridcell

I have a wpf application with a datagrid. That datagrid contains double numbers on his cells with 15-16 decimals sometimes. I want to hide all that decimals on lost focus and show just 2 or 3, but keeping the real number stored because I don't want to lose precission. The same on got focus, showing all the decimals.

I've thought to do this creating a custom datagrid cell and making that changes on the OnGotFocus()/OnLostFocus() methods, but I don't know if that is the best way to do this. Thanks in advance and sorry about my english.

Comment: Don't you want this the other way round? Because it seems more logical to me to show less decimals when it is not focused.

Comment: You're right @Silvermind, I'll edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to use

```
ColumnWidth="SizeToHeader"
```

in my datagrid definition in WPF. Now when a number is bigger than the header, the datagrid doesn't grow, so that made the trick for me at the moment.